# Fundamental question on spring and tension forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

Consider two situations when a body of mass $m$ is suspended freely by:

> **(I)** A string
>
> **(II)** A spring

Now we cut the string/spring. What would be the acceleration of the body just after we cut them?

> **In case(I)** :It would be $\mathbf g$(acceleration due to gravity) itself.(I have no doubt here)
>
> **In case(II)**: I am not sure what would happen. At equilibrium the *spring* exerts an upward Force of $Kx=mg$ on the body. On cutting it, I think that an extra compensating Force of $Kx=mg$ acts in the downward direction on the body,so would the acceleration of the body be $2g$?

Is there a way we can explain this difference in behavior of tension and spring forces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after being separated from whatever is holding it, the only force on the body is gravity. So, its acceleration is $g$ in both cases.

A spring is supposed to accept a bigger deformation for a given force. So, it will oscillate with greater amplitude after the separation..

Comment: Oh yes sorry I misread a line from my Book. It said Kx or mg, I misread it as Kx+mg.